# "import and using may not appear after a type declaration" -- the haxe using magic

Tags: generics, haxe, type-parameter

I am trying to add an less-than-or-equal-to method (non-intrusively) to basic types such as Int, Float or existing/library types that I cannot change. (see my other question [how to write a generic compare function in Haxe (haxe3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711203/how-to-write-a-generic-compare-function-in-haxe-haxe3)) I read that the "using" keyword is the way to do it.

What I intend to do is this:

```
class IntOrder {
    static public function le(x:Int,y:Int):Bool { return x <= y; }
}
class FloatOrder {
    static public function le(x:Float,y:Float):Bool { return x <= y; }
}
class StringOrder {
    static public function le(x:String,y:String):Bool {... }
}
//...Other classes

using IntOrder;
using FloatOrder;
using StringOrder;
//... Other using statements

class Main {
    @:generic static public function compare_<A:{function le(y:A):Bool;}>(x:A,y:A): Int {
        if (x.le(y) && y.le(x)) return 0;
        else if (x.le(y)) return -1;
        else se return 1;
    }
}
```

Now haxe3.01 is giving an error: `import and using may not appear after a type declaration`.

I understand that `using` is a kind of special `import` statement, so probably one can't import inside the same file where the declaration is made. 
My questions are:

1) in a use-case like this one, do I have to create a three-line file for each of the `XXXOrder` classes? This is rather a pain to maintain.

2) even if I create separate .hx files for each `XXXOrder` class, will the same function name (e.g. `le`) cause name clashes.

3) Is there a way to work around the `using` keyword (maybe using callback??) so that these extender classes can be hold in one file?

Thanks in advance.

--- Update ---
I tried moving `using` statements before the class definitions as suggested in the answer. Now compiler is not complaining about the `using` statement. But it's complaining about type check failure.

```
using Main.IntOrder;
using Main.FloatOrder;
using Main.StringOrder;

class IntOrder {
    static public function le(x:Int,y:Int):Bool { return x <= y; }
}
class FloatOrder {
    static public function le(x:Float,y:Float):Bool { return x <= y; }
}
class StringOrder {
    static public function le(x:String,y:String):Bool { return true; }
}

class Main {
    @:generic static public function compare_<A:{function le(y:A):Bool;}>(x:A,y:A): Int {
        if (x.le(y) && y.le(x)) return 0;
        else if (x.le(y)) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
    static public function main() {
        Sys.print(compare_(1,2));
    }
}
```

returns:

```
Main.hx:22: characters 12-25 : Constraint check failure for compare_.A
Main.hx:22: characters 12-25 : Int should be { le : y : Int -> Bool }
```

It seems that x.le(y) still does not work inside compare_.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to move the `using` statements to the top and reference the class using a full path (package.Module.Class).

Haxe defined that

> Following the principles of shadowing, the latest types imported
>   always have priority over the previous ones.

So to allow IntOrder not to be always shadowed, put it under FloatOrder.

Here is the demo:
http://try.haxe.org/#8E07D

```
using Test.FloatOrder;
using Test.IntOrder;

class IntOrder {
  static public function le(x:Int,y:Int) return "IntOrder";
}
class FloatOrder {
  static public function le(x:Float,y:Float) return "FloatOrder";
}

class Test {

  static function main():Void {
    trace(1.le(1)); //IntOrder
    trace(1.1.le(1)); //FloatOrder
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I never found an example of `using` where the target is defined in place.

Comment: the generated `.le()` still does not work for the original example. Any ideas?