# How to use operators between types of Haxe generic classes?

Tags: generics, operators, haxe

I'd like to use common comparison operators (like `<`, `>` or `==`) between the instances of generic class types, like that ([try.haxe.org](https://try.haxe.org/#6292B69B)):

```
class Comp<T> {

  var _val: T;

  public function new(val: T) _val = val;

  // leads to error: Cannot compare Comp.T and Comp.T
  public function gt(val: T):Bool return _val > val;

}

class Test {

  static function main() {
    var intComp = new Comp<Int>(5);
    trace(intComp.gt(3));
    trace(intComp.gt(6));
    
    var strComp = new Comp<String>("baz");
    trace(strComp.gt("bar"));
    trace(strComp.gt("foo"));
  }

}
```

With this code I've got compile time error -- "Cannot compare Comp.T and Comp.T". It makes sense because you never know what T type is and will it be comparable by common operators. But my concrete calls `new Comp<Int>` or `new Comp<String>` are clearly showing that this operations are possible.

How to limit T class with only "operator's comparable" types, like `class Comp<T:HaveComparisonOperators>`? Or probably should I say to the compiler not to analyze code of generic class before it coerced with concrete type? Surely, I can make both variants for Int and String types, but code will be almost the same excluding type declarations at the methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to properly constrain that.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711203/how-to-write-a-generic-compare-function-in-haxe-haxe3

Comment: I think it's very strange behavior of generics, because they can't exist without provided types. Looks like compiler optimization or build precautions.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, Haxe could be improved to use constraint like Int|String, unfortunately only Int&String is supported which is meaningless.

However, you can use abstract type to get job done, wonder if it could be optimized.

```
abstract Comparable(Dynamic) from Int from String to Int to String {
  @:op(A > B)
  public static function gt(lhs, rhs:Dynamic):Bool {
    return (lhs:Dynamic) > rhs;
  }
}

class Comp<T:Comparable> {

  var _val: Comparable;

  public function new(val: T) _val = val;

  public function gt(val:T):Bool return _val > val;

}

class Test {

  static function main() {
    var intComp = new Comp<Int>(5);
    trace(intComp.gt(3));
    trace(intComp.gt(6));
    
    var strComp = new Comp<String>("baz");
    trace(strComp.gt("bar"));
    trace(strComp.gt("foo"));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting working solution. But it strictly depends on passing all used classes to Comparable from/to sections. For example, if I have surely comparable type like `abstract ID(Int) from Int to Int` attempt to call `new Comp<ID>(new ID(1))` will lead to compile error.

Comment: You need to add constructor like public function new(v:Int) this = v to ID first, then you need to update Comparable (to and from section) by adding ID. Otherwise, ID is not  recognized as Comparable type.

Comment: I've done one [weird example](https://try.haxe.org/#9d3C7a58) and don't really understand what's going on.

Comment: I have seen generated js code and it became more clear. Direct comparing arrays is just js feature. Other targets are behaving more predictable. But I've supposed that all targets will fail to compile last pair of types.

Comment: Nothing is going to fail if you do it right. Abstracts are most powerful runtime feature, while macros are most powerful compile time feature. Use in-lining over Abstracts to avoid (static) functions, combine that with macros and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to [override type checking](https://try.haxe.org/#59719d33) and think that it's very bad solution, but it's working:

```
class Comp<T> {

  var _val: T;

  public function new(val: T) _val = val;

  public function gt(val:T):Bool return (_val:Dynamic) > (val:Dynamic);

}

abstract Entity(Int) from Int to Int {
  public function new(val) this = val;
}

typedef IntArray = Array<Int>;

class AnyClass {
  public function new(a) {}
}

class Test {

  static function main() {
    var intComp = new Comp<Int>(5);
    trace(intComp.gt(3));
    trace(intComp.gt(6));
    
    var strComp = new Comp<String>("baz");
    trace(strComp.gt("bar"));
    trace(strComp.gt("foo"));
    
    var entComp = new Comp<Entity>(new Entity(55));
    trace(entComp.gt(new Entity(33)));
    trace(entComp.gt(new Entity(66)));
    
    var shouldFail1 = new Comp<IntArray>([5, 5]); // JS will just compare arrays, voila
    trace(shouldFail1.gt([5, 3]));
    trace(shouldFail1.gt([5, 6]));
    
    var shouldFail2 = new Comp<AnyClass>(new AnyClass(5)); // WTF???
    trace(shouldFail2.gt(new AnyClass(3)));
    trace(shouldFail2.gt(new AnyClass(6)));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's very bad idea for sure... It have serious performance hit on casting primitive types to dynamic.

Comment: You are making class with no safe guard: T can be anything, leading to should fail assumptions, performance problems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make things simple, don't overdo it.

```
typedef IntArray = Array<Int>;

abstract Comparable(Dynamic) from ID from Int from String to ID to Int to String {
  @:op(A > B)
  public static inline function gt(lhs, rhs:Dynamic):Bool {
    return (lhs:Dynamic) > rhs;
  }
}

class Comp<T:Comparable> {

  var _val: Comparable;

  public function new(val: T) _val = val;

  public function gt(val:T):Bool return _val > val;
}

abstract ID(Int) from Int to Int {
    public inline function new(v:Int) this = v;
}

class AnyClass {
  public function new(a) {}
}

class Test {

  static function main() {
    var intComp:Comparable = new ID(1);
    trace(intComp > 3);
    trace(intComp > 6);
    
    var strComp:Comparable = "baz";
    trace(strComp > "bar");
    trace(strComp > "foo");

    var shouldFail1 = new Comp<IntArray>([5, 5]); // Constraint check failure ... IntArray should be Comparable
    var shouldFail2 = new Comp<AnyClass>(new AnyClass(5)); // Constraint check failure ... AnyClass should be Comparable
  }
}
```